# borderless prometheus buckets

Tags: histogram, prometheus

to have a working prometheus histogram i need a bucket which is a set of values that when passed to `observe` method(i use https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby) will be recorded. so when my bucket is :

```
[1,2,3, 100]
```

its going to record `1` as `1`, `2.1` as `2` etc.

how can i make it record everything between 3 and 100 without explicitly passing values to the bucket?
how can i make it record  values from `1` to `infinity` like here https://hexdocs.pm/prometheus_ex/Prometheus.Buckets.html ?

Answer (score 4):

A histogram is represented as a set of counters where each counter represents a bucket. It is typically used to track latency.

Each bucket stores a number representing events **less** than the bucket value.

```
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="1.0",} 16.0
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="2.0",} 16.0
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="3.0",} 16.0
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="100.0",} 16.0
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf",} 16.0
```

The `le` label come from the array passed to the histogram upon initilization.

> how can i make it record everything between 3 and 100 without explicitly passing values to the bucket?

You need to pass the specific values of 3 and 100 explicitly. Moreover, you can't directly get everything between 3 and 100, you need to subtract the following to get this number.

```
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="100.0",} - hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="3.0",}
```

> How can i make it record values from 1 to infinity

Same technique as above:

```
hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf",} - hello_world_latency_seconds_bucket{le="1.0",}
```